# Iterating array over array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, game-engine

I am writing a simple game with a simple collision detection system.

I currently have this code for iterating the array over the same array so i can check if the objects are close to each other and if they will collide:

```js
var objects = []; //assume this is not empty


for(i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
  for(a=0;a<objects.length;a++){
    if(a != i){
      //collision handling
    }
  }
}
```

But the main problem with this code is that I have duplicates.
For example I check i and a but somewhere later i check a and i with the same values.

I tried using an array that saves which objects are checked with which objects but it gives me a big fps drop.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: what is the content of the `objects` array?

Comment: It's just and array which contains circles with x position, y position , radius and x and y vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start your second `for` loop in the current place of the first `for` loop:

```
for(i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
    for(a=i+1;a<objects.length;a++){
      //collision handling
    }
}
```

This way you check every item in your array only against the items ahead of the current item.

lets check your original code:

```js
objects = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for(i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
  for(a=0;a<objects.length;a++){
    if(a != i){
      console.log("Checking "+ objects[i]+ "vs. "+objects[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, lets check my example:

```js
objects = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for(i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
  for(a=i+1;a<objects.length;a++){
    console.log("Checking "+ objects[i]+ "vs. "+objects[a]);
  }
}
```

The general idea is to compare every item only to the items that are followed in the array:

```
[a, b, c, d]
 a => vs b, c, d    ar[0] vs ar[1], ar[2], ar[3]
    b => vs c, d    ar[1] vs        ar[2], ar[3]
       c => vs d    ar[2] vs               ar[3]
```

Comment: It is not the same code, this is better since it is not making the same checks....

Comment: @Roberrrt, this is not. This way you don't have duplicates check on objects[2] vs objects[5] and later-on objects[5] vs objects[2].

Comment: @epascarello, any idea regarding the downvoting?

Comment: This is not solving my problem.

Comment: So your question is how to check if two objects are equal?

Comment: I do think this is the correct answer. It's more performant since it implicitly skips any duplicate indeces and only checks unique ones in the array.

Comment: No, i need to compare every single item in the array with every other single item in the array without comparing two single items twice.

Comment: Oh sorry. It works! I thought it was not going to work but i was wrong. Now, i just don't understand how this works.

Comment: The snippets don't work, so you can run it locally... or wait for them to come back :) I think you will understand when they will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES2015, `Set` allows only unique members of the set. From MDN:

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```
[...new Set(objects)]
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the OP needs.  OP is not asking for a way to prevent duplicates.  OP needs a way to make unique comparisons (without making the same comparison twice).

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear when I posted my answer. Thank you @devlincarnate for clearing it up though